# Is it possibel to get that "Padlock" symbol in the address bar for a localhost https connection that uses a self signed certificate?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I am currenlty implemented SSL for my Web App in tomcat using a self signed certificate using java Keystore tool.

I am using the web app in my machine as localhost. When I visit the url

```
https://localhost:8443
```

the padlock symbol not appears in the address bar but the page loads successfully .

Why this happening ?

Comment: Have you checked whether you had mixed content?

Comment: @Bruno .. For all  content , no padlock

Comment: Yes it is possible. I'm not sure what browser you are using but you must import the certificate into the browser - probably as a CA certificate. How you checked out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509700/ssl-in-tomcat-7 ?

Comment: Just to be sure, I mean all content used by the page (scripts, images, ...) you should be able to check that with the developer tools. Which browser are you using, by the way?